# When describing an action in a picture should I use present progressive or simple tense?

Tags: tense, present-participles, present-simple

When describing an action in a picture should I use *present progressive tense* or *present simple tense*?

For example if I want to write a title for the following picture, it should be:

> "This gentleman **asks** his girlfriend "will you marry me"

or

> "This gentleman **is asking** his girlfriend "will you marry me"
>   ?

[image]

Comment: Why are you writing a title? I ask because **guy** is too informal for say a magazine. If your homework is to describe the action, the answer would be different. If you need to describe the action in the image, then how much detail do you need?

Comment: I'd go with "is asking", since a photograph is of an event in progress, and every time you view the event, the event is perpetually "happening"

Comment: @WillowRex Then I've changed it to gentleman. But anyway my question issue is about the tense.

Comment: @mstorkson  In the past I think that I've been told that in titles the using is in present tense (even in things that they are in present progressive). But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

> "This gentleman asks his girlfriend,  "Will you marry me?"

Please note added comma, capital and question mark.

> "This gentleman is asking his girlfriend, "Will you marry me?"

Please note added comma, capital and question mark. I prefer this example, but the first is fine.

If it is a caption for a publication, you can drop some words:

**Gentleman Asks Girlfriend to Marry Him**   (More capitals, no commas or periods.)

If you are meant to describe the image:

The young man is proposing. He is down on one knee and has brought (brings) his girlfriend gifts to show how serious he is about his proposal. The young woman looks quite disinterested.